# ggplot stacked bar plot from 2 separate data frames

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have been struggling with this conundrum all day and getting close, but no cigar. I have two data frames which are the results of two separate socio-economic surveys from two districts within a city. I want to compare columns from these data frames side by side in a bar plot to show the frequencies (counts) of responses to a particular question across both surveys.

The questions asked in each survey were identical. However, they were coded slightly differently and therefore the column names are slightly different as follows! I have managed to plot data from my two data frames (`ar` and `bn`) on the same bar plot with the raw data i.e. without having to merge the data frames. However, I seem unable to plot stacked bar plots side-by-side.

I used ggplot2 with the following code:

```
    ggplot(bn, aes(A8_HHH_hig, fill=A6_Sex_HHH))
+ geom_bar(position="stack", alpha=0.5) 
+ geom_bar(data=ar, aes(A9_HHHedulevl, fill=A7_HHsex), position="stack", alpha=0.5)
```

Which produces this:
[image]

As you'll notice I am attempting to plot the split between male and female respondents based on their highest level of schooling for the two data frames. (Note the sex of the respondent is also coded differently in each data frame i.e. male/m and female/f.)

I'd really like these two stacked bar plots to be plotted on the same grid, side by side so it is easy for me to compare values. However, I'm not entirely sure if I can use the `position="dodge"` option here, as the values come from different dataframes.

Does anyone know if this is possible?! Or perhaps another way of comparing these values, visually?

I've attached some reproducible code if anyone has the time to have a look!

thanks

> dput(ar)

```
structure(list(District = c("Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi"), A9_HHHedulevl = structure(c(9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 
6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
3L), .Label = c("Adult Education", "Junior Secondary", "koranic", 
"NCE", "None", "Polytechnic", "Senior Primary", "Senior Secondary", 
"University"), class = "factor"), A7_HHsex = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("District", 
"A9_HHHedulevl", "A7_HHsex"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 46L, 47L, 
48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 
61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 
74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 
87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 
100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 
111L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 
123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 
134L), class = "data.frame", na.action = structure(131:135, .Names = c("135", 
"136", "137", "138", "139"), class = "omit"))
```

> dput(bn)

```
structure(list(District = c("Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa"), A8_HHH_hig = structure(c(7L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 
12L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 10L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 12L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 11L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 11L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 12L, 11L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 12L, 12L, 
4L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 12L, 2L, 5L, 12L, 7L, 
10L, 10L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 10L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
3L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 
7L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
10L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 9L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 6L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 12L, 
10L, 5L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 1L), .Label = c("Adult Education", 
"Junior Primary", "Junior Secondary", "Koranic", "NCE", "None", 
"Polytechnic", "Prelim / JMB", "Senior Primary", "Senior Secondary", 
"Technical College", "University"), class = "factor"), A6_Sex_HHH = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("District", 
"A8_HHH_hig", "A6_Sex_HHH"), row.names = c(NA, 196L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is an example of the kind of thing I am looking to produce:

[image]

```
structure(list(sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor"), 
education = structure(c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 
9L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 4L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
6L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 12L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
6L, 8L, 7L, 12L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
6L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
6L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 4L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 
8L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 
8L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 
6L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 
9L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 
6L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L), .Label = c("Adult Education", 
"Junior Secondary", "Koranic", "NCE", "None", "Polytechnic", 
"Senior Primary", "Senior Secondary", "University", "Junior Primary", 
"Prelim / JMB", "Technical College"), class = "factor"), 
district = c("Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", "Angwan Rimi", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", 
"Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa", "Barnawa")), .Names = c("sex", 
"education", "district"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
"19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", 
"30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", 
"41", "42", "43", "44", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", 
"53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", 
"64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", 
"75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", 
"86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", 
"97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", 
"107", "108", "109", "110", "111", "113", "114", "115", "116", 
"117", "118", "119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", 
"126", "127", "128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", 
"135", "136", "137", "138", "139", "1361", "1371", "1381", "1391", 
"140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", "148", 
"149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155", "156", "157", 
"158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", "164", "165", "166", 
"167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", "173", "174", "175", 
"176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", "182", "183", "184", 
"185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", "191", "192", "193", 
"194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", "200", "201", "202", 
"203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", "209", "210", "211", 
"212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", "218", "219", "220", 
"221", "222", "223", "224", "225", "226", "227", "228", "229", 
"230", "231", "232", "233", "234", "235", "236", "237", "238", 
"239", "240", "241", "242", "243", "244", "245", "246", "247", 
"248", "249", "250", "251", "252", "253", "254", "255", "256", 
"257", "258", "259", "260", "261", "262", "263", "264", "265", 
"266", "267", "268", "269", "270", "271", "272", "273", "274", 
"275", "276", "277", "278", "279", "280", "281", "282", "283", 
"284", "285", "286", "287", "288", "289", "290", "291", "292", 
"293", "294", "295", "296", "297", "298", "299", "300", "301", 
"302", "303", "304", "305", "306", "307", "308", "309", "310", 
"311", "312", "313", "314", "315", "316", "317", "318", "319", 
"320", "321", "322", "323", "324", "325", "326", "327", "328", 
"329", "330", "331"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason not to merge (more accurately: `rbind`) the data frames?

Comment: ggplot can cope with multiple dataframes (just add `geom_bar(data = xx`...) but you really should just merge these data frames.

Comment: Please explain more what you mean when you say "plot side by side". Do you mean two plots, or discrete columns for each district for each x value, on the same axes?

Comment: hi, I've edited the original post to show an example of a plot I created in Excel. This has three stacked bars per category plotted side by side. This is the kind of thing I want to recreate in R as it was not fun to produce in Excel and looks pretty horrible!

Comment: Thanks for the new plot showing what you want to produce. Unfortunately, R won't make a plot look any better. I would really encourage you to plot this using facets; see edited answer. Depending on what you really want to show, you could split out data and show this on a map, for example - do the bars really tell you anything?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a workaround for this problem because directly in one `ggplot2` plot you can't combine dodging and stacking.

For this plot I used the data frame `all_data` that is made @DrewSteen answer - data frame should contain values for all `District` levels.

The idea is to plot on x axis combination of `District` and `A8_HHH_hig`. This is achieved with function `interaction()` inside the `aes()` call. Then this is converted to numeric to ensure that later we can add labels at positions we want. For the `fill=` we again use combination - now between `sex` and `District`. To get labels for the x axis use `scale_x_continuous()` and set break points at 2,4,6,...,26 (values between two bars that are of the same education level, maximal value is calculated as number of levels of `A8_HHH_hig` * levels of `Sex`) and as labels provide levels of `A8_HHH_hig`.

```
ggplot(all_data,aes(as.numeric(interaction(District,A8_HHH_hig)),
                        fill=interaction(sex,District)))+
       geom_bar(binwidth=1)+
       theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-45, hjust=0))+
     scale_x_continuous("Education",breaks=seq(2,26,2),
          labels=levels(all_data$A8_HHH_hig),expand=c(0,0.5),limits=c(1,27))+
     scale_fill_discrete("",
          labels=c("Female Angwan","Male  Angwan","Female Barnawa","Male Barnawa"))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! that's it exactly. I don't quite understand the breaks and labeling arguments though as when trying to recreate the plot above I get `Error: Breaks and labels have unequal lengths` n.b. have added my new data frame 'arbn_edu' above, where I've cleaned and joined my existing two data frames...

Comment: @marty_c Check how many levels has your education variable (A8_HHH_hig) and then multiply it with 2 (there are 2 sex), For example, if there is 15 levels, then in breaks= you should write seq(2,30,2)

Comment: I like the workaround, but I think that's a really hard plot to digest. And I hope no-one is colorblind...

Comment: @AndyClifton I could agree with you, just showed the way to do it in ggplot2

Answer (score 2):

### Basic bar charts

Consolidate the data into one data.frame and tidy up your data.

Here goes:

```
# fix the names
names(ar)[2] <- "highest"
names(ar)[3] <- "gender"
names(bn)[2] <- "highest"
names(bn)[3] <- "gender"
data <-rbind(ar,bn)
data$gender[data$gender =="M"] <- "male"
data$gender[data$gender =="F"] <- "female"


# plots
require('ggplot2')
theme_bw(base_size = 8, base_family = "")
p2 <- ggplot(data, aes(highest, fill=gender)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", alpha=0.5) +  
  facet_wrap(~District, ncol = 3) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
print(p2)

ggsave(filename = "DistrictGender.png",
       plot = p2,
       scale = 1,
       width = 5, height = 3,
       dpi = 300)
```

and this is what you get:

[image]

For suggestions on how to improve the plot, see the ggplot2 manual: http://ggplot2.org

### Alternative plots

A bar chart really only works when you have a small number of data sets to show. Once you have more that ~ 6 districts, the reader will start to lose the ability to process the data that is being presented. So, you may need to think about some alternatives.

What about using maps:

- If you can get a latitude and longitude for each district, plot circles on a map showing the count in each district. You'd do a separate facet for male and female, and separate maps for each level.
- If you can get shape files of the districts, you can plot these as [choropleths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choropleth_map).

Comment: Hi all thanks for the comments. I have also been experimenting with a solution to rbind the dataframes, however what I've shown you is a snippet from two large datasets which each have over 100 columns. This was one answer to a single question from a 60 question questionnaire. I was trying to avoid having to merge the data frames and wondered if it would be possible to get some quick analysis out just using ggplot2.

Comment: It sounds like you need to rethink your data processing. For example, you may want to think instead of melting your data together, so that you can use the faceting capability of `ggplot2`. That said, that's unrelated to your original question: maybe you could accept one or other of the answers you've been offered, and ask another question about the larger data set?

Comment: I've tried faceting but I didn't feel it offered the visual impact that I need. Although the answers above get me close to where I need to be, I still haven't figured out a way to produce the plot above for two districts e.g. for each level of educational attainment, I am trying to show a stacked bar for each district, side-by-side, which was my original question

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a specific reason not to bind the data frames, this should work

```
require(plyr) # for the rename function
ar_rename <- rename(ar, replace=c("A9_HHHedulevl" = "A8_HHH_hig", "A7_HHsex"="A6_Sex_HHH"))
all_data <- rbind(ar_rename, bn)

# Create a new column for a 'unified' sex variable
#    There are shorter ways to do this, but I like this way
#    because it is very easy to read.
all_data$sex <- "F"
all_data$sex[all_data$A6_Sex_HHH == "male" | all_data$A6_Sex_HHH == "M"] <- "M"

# Plot the data, using position="dodge"
ggplot(all_data, aes(x=A8_HHH_hig, fill=sex)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", alpha=0.5) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-45, hjust=0)) # to make the axis labels legible
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for these two methods. I had achieved something similar with plyr, however, I should have mentioned I also need to compare responses to these questions by District - whereas both of the charts above have merged results from both districts. I actually need one chart showing male/female responses to educational attainment, split by district to make a comparison between educational attainment by district. Ideally then, the above chart would have two sets of stacked bars, stacked by sex (m/f) with each set of bars represent a single district...